# Windows wchar_t to char conversion errors

Tags: windows

I have been following this code from "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Directx 10" and I am typing out the main class. While I was typing I noticed a few errors. I tryed googling them but there were no results. So I ask you if you can help me.

The code:

```
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, 0, &mDepthStencilBuffer));
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilBuffer, 0,  &mDepthStencilView));
    HR(mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0));
```

where the error is:
 "argument type 'const wchar_t*' is incompatible with parameter of 'const char*'"

and

```
 wcscpy(fontDesc.FaceName, L"Times New Roman");
```

where the error is:
"argument of type 'CHAR*' is incompatible with parameter of type 'wchar_t*'"
**EDIT:** The error is at `fontDesc.FaceName`

Comment: This is off topic for gamedev. It's not strictly related to game development and is a general coding problem. Coding related questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com. The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're using the wrong types in your functions.

Comment: Might want to back up and focus on learning C++ before doing DirectX.

Comment: @ClassicThunder - this specific problem isn't C++, it's Unicode vs Multi-byte in the project settings, but agree that the OP needs to back up a little and agree that this is a general programming question and shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this isn't strictly a gamedev question, but it was easy to answer.  Assuming you're using Visual Studio, you need to enable Unicode in the project settings:

[image]

Make sure "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" are selected, then under the "General" tab, select "Use Unicode Character Set" as shown.  Then rebuild the solution and those errors should go away.

Comment: Sorry for being in wrong section. But thank-you so much!